# how to upgrade phpmyadmin after installing mysql 5.6

Tags: 12.04, mysql, phpmyadmin

After upgrading MySQL from 5.5 to 5.6 I got the following error in phpmyadmin:

> Your PHP MySQL library version 5.5.33 differs from your MySQL server
>   version 5.6.13. This may cause unpredictable behavior.

The problem would be solved by installing  `php5-msqlnd` but the repository for `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS` didn't fix the issue as it says [in this launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phpmyadmin/+bug/1227205)

Installing via `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin` will warn the user that `php5-mysqlnd` will be marked removed and `php5-mysql` will be marked install

this is the output I got from the command: `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`

```
> The following extra packages will be installed:   php5-mysql Suggested
> packages:   mysql-server The following packages will be REMOVED:  
> php5-mysqlnd The following NEW packages will be installed:  
> php5-mysql phpmyadmin
```

Thus I will loose `mysqlnd` which is the new improved driver for mysql api

The suggested workaround is to play with dependencies string which I don't like because it's not the right way to solve this issue.

How can I install phpmyadmin with mysqlnd to support mysql 5.6 in ubuntu 12.04 without playing with  dependencies string in the package config

Answer (score 5):

The solution I found is to add a custom PPA and install phpmyadmin with mysqlnd without any problem like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nijel/phpmyadmin
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd

sudo apt-get remove  phpmyadmin --purge
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install phpmyadmin` will do the work of the last two commands (and will avoid leaving the user without phpmyadmin if their Internet connection is interrupted, because necessary packages are downloaded before the purge operation is performed).

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04 I was able to install `php5-mysqlnd` without any additional repo.  Also It was important to drop the phpmyadmin before reinstalling to get rid of `Connection for controluser failed` error.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem on Ubuntu 14.04 by uninstalling and re-installing phpMyAdmin:

```
sudo apt-get remove phpmyadmin  # Note: I did NOT purge the phpMyAdmin database
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

After re-installing the warning no longer appeared.

Comment: This can also be accomplished with `sudo apt-get --reinstall install phpmyadmin`. This has the benefit that, if files have to be downloaded for the reinstallation, they will be downloaded before the package is uninstalled. (That way, Internet connection problems won't leave the user without `phpmyadmin`.)